# Why does copper precipitate out as a pink solid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color

When copper is precipitated out of a solution e.g from CuI, why does it appear pink instead of copper-coloured? Are there other situations where copper appears pink in solid form?

Answer (score 17):

What you describe as pink is the actual colour of copper. The colour of a clean, solid surface of high-purity copper is typically salmon red. In your case, the appearance may be further affected by the particle size of the precipitate.

The familiar reddish-brown colour of copper is caused by copper(I) oxide, which is slowly formed on the metal surface.