# Copper brightness change

Tags: electrochemistry

In an electrolysis situation I have identified a slight brightness change on a copper electrode.
What might have happened?

I'm dealing with different experiments and this reaction occurs in some of them.
In this experiment I am doing an electrolysis using a water solution with $\ce{NaCl}$, a Lechanché and two copper bars. The brightness change happens on the anode.

I also get bubbles and a color change in the solution of the cathode, I'm guessing it is due to the reduction of water.

Comment: Related: [Why does copper precipitate out as a pink solid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/29736/7951)

Answer (score 1):

If an aqueous solution of $\ce{NaCl}$ is electrolyzed between copper electrodes, the most important reaction taking place on the anode is the dissolution of copper, according to : $$\ce{Cu -> Cu^{2+} + 2e^-}$$ If the copper plate was well polished and shiny like a mirror, the corrosion reaction will first occur on the smallest crystals, which are inserted between bigger regular crystals. As a consequence, the surface will be irregularly attacked, and its aspect will loose its shiny appearance.

Of course, at the cathode, some Hydrogen gas is produced.

Answer (score 0):

My take on the possible chemistry starting with the [electrolysis of salt water](https://aquarius.oceansciences.org/cgi/ed_act.htm?id=47#:%7E:text=Electrolysis%20of%20an%20aqueous%20solution,usually%20only%20in%20minute%20amounts.&text=Hydrogen%20gas%20will%20be%20seen,will%20bubble%20at%20the%20anode.), which can produce some chlorine. The latter can further react with water as follows:

$\ce{Cl2 + H2O <=> H+ + Cl- + HOCl}$

The created Hypochlorous acid may react with cuprous (here present as a $\ce{Cu2O}$ on the copper metal electrode). A fenton-type reaction based on $\ce{HOCl}$ could then proceed as follows for $\mathrm{pH > 5}$:

> $\ce{Cu(I) (s) + HOCl (aq) -> Cu(II) (aq) + ^.OH (aq) + Cl- (aq) }$

The dissolving of the $\ce{Cu2O}$ results in a de facto cleaning of the copper metal surface, which per [a reference](https://www.hunker.com/12003519/what-takes-off-green-stuff-off-copper) to quote:

> Copper is a beautiful burnished-gold color when it is clean and well maintained, but like all metals, copper can become discolored when exposed to air and water.

For background on the fenton-type reaction, see "Fenton chemistry in biology and medicine" by Josef Prousek, to quote reaction (15) on page 2330, to quote:

> For $\ce{Fe(II)}$ and $\ce{Cu(I)}$, this situation can be generally depicted as follows [20,39]
>
> $\ce{ Fe(II)/Cu(I) + HOX -> Fe(III)/Cu(II) + HO^. + X- }$ (15)
>
> where $\ce{X = Cl, ONO}$, and $\ce{SCN}$.